# Filter by NULL in DataTable.Compute()

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to execute the following code -

```
dt.Compute("Count(RetailerId)", "SurveyorDate<>NULL")
```

But it's not giving me the expected result. **SurveyorDate** might by DBNull.Value. I would like to sort them out in my filter expression.

How can i do that?

Comment: If the second parameter is using SQL Server syntax, you can't use <> with null. Try `SurveyorDate is not null`. (Not an answer as I'm not sure)

Comment: @ George T your suggestion works. Post it as answer. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, those arguments form part of an SQL query and use MS SQL Server syntax.

SQL Server does not allow comparing to null using equality operators such as ==, != or <>. Instead, use the "is [not] null" syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx